# Consul ACL - Policies

Tags: acl, consul

I have a DataCenter in Consul. I would like to implement ACL, using terraform.

I mainly care about these assumptions:

- Everyone has access to the GUI without a token
- CLI/API is only available with a token.

Question: Is this setting possible?